# Keras deviance custom loss

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I am trying to use deviance as a custom loss function for optimizing a neural network wuth keras. I tried this :

```
#building model
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(Dense(10, input_dim = 6, activation = "relu"))
model.add(Dense(5, activation = "relu"))
model.add(Dense(1, activation = "sigmoid"))

#DEF CUSTOM LOSS
def custom_loss():
    def loss(y_true, y_pred):
        return (2. *(KB.log(y_true) - KB.log(y_pred)))
    return loss


model.compile(loss = custom_loss(), optimizer = 'sgd')
model.fit(factorsTrain, yTrain, epochs = 2)
```

But it gives -inf as the loss so i guess it doesn't work properly at all, is there something i did wrong in there ?

Edit : I changed the activation to exponential in last layer to ensure values are between 0 and 1. I also noticed that since some of my y_true (most of them in fact) are equal to 0 i changed the loss function to this (also added epsilon which is 1e-07 to make sure i don't calculate the ln(0) :

```
#DEF CUSTOM LOSS
def custom_loss():
    def loss(y_true, y_pred):

        return (( KB.sqrt( KB.square(2 * (KB.log(y_true + KB.epsilon()) -    KB.log(y_pred + KB.epsilon())) ))))
    return loss
```

Now i don't get -inf anymore but i still get NaN instead

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix it by changing the formula a little bit in order to force the values inside logs to be >= 0

```
def Deviance_loss():
    def loss(y_true, y_pred):
        y_true = KB.max(y_true, 0)
        return (KB.sqrt(KB.square( 2 * KB.log(y_true + KB.epsilon()) - KB.log(y_pred))))
    return loss
```